# Calling a base page method from a user control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, user-controls

I have been trying to find a good answer to this question, but can't seem to find one. I have an ASP.NET page that derives from a base page, like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : MyBasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loginTime = GetLoginTime(); // This works fine
    }
}
```

And the base page:

```
public partial class MyBasePage: Page
{
}

protected DateTime GetLoginTime()
{
    // Do stuff
    return loginTime;
}
```

Now I have a user control on that page that needs to call my method...Like this:

```
public partial class TimeClock : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loginTime = GetLoginTime(); // This does not work!
    }
}
```

As you can see, I cannot call my base method, for obvious reasons. My question is, how can I call this method from my user control? One work around I've found is like this:

```
var page = Parent as MyBasePage;
page.GetLoginTime(); // This works IF I make GetLoginTime() a public method
```

This works, if I make my function public instead of protected. Doing this doesn't seem like a very OOP way to tackle this solution, so if someone can offer me a better solution, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You seem to have it correct. UserControl does not inherit BasePage. I am not sure what you are after. In cases like this I would add a public property to the UserControl and set it from the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimeClock inherits from UserControl, not from MyBasePage so why should TimeClock see the Method GetLoginTime()?

Comment: Daniel - It wouldn't. It makes sense why it wouldn't. I'm looking for a solution on how I can call this function though

Comment: Make a static class called "Helper" or something like that and implement a static method called GetLoginTime(). Problem is, what should the method GetLoginTime() do? Or implement it static in the global.asax file if you want to get a session value...

Comment: Yeah I like that idea...I can make it internal static and that solution would work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your UserControl out of your Page stuff. It should be decoupled in OOP speak. Add properties to set values and delegates to hook into events:

```
public partial class TimeClock : UserControl
{
    public DateTime LoginTime{ get; set; }

    public event UserControlActionHandler ActionEvent;
    public delegate void UserControlActionHandler (object sender, EventArgs e);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (this.ActionEvent!= null)
       {
           this.ActionEvent(sender, e);
       }
    }

}
```

Page

```
public partial class MainPage : MyBasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loginTime = GetLoginTime();
        TimeClock1.LoginTime = loginTime;
        TimeClock1.ActionEvent += [tab][tab]...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(this.Page as BasePage).MethodName()